# While running crontab- Error- Java is not accessible(fatal)

Tags: java, cron

I want to run few scripts at specific time everyday. I configured it in crontab, and while I run it I see the error "Java is not accessible(fatal problem)". While running the same scripts individually, I don't see any errors.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously it's the environment available to the job started by cron - you need to add java to the path. Easiest  thing to do is just dump the environment in a cron job and see what is there (and it's not much).